# Codewar task. How to find simple square numbers by the condition?

Tags: c#, algorithm

**I tried to solve this problem on Codewar, but I don`t understand how to find exceptions.**

In this Kata, you will be given a number n (n > 0) and your task will be to return the smallest square number N (N > 0) such that n + N is also a perfect square. If there is no answer, return -1 (nil in Clojure, Nothing in Haskell).

Here code that I wrote:

```
using System;

public class SqNum
{
    public static long solve(long n){  
       int N = 1;
            long lTemp = n;
            double sum, result;
            bool isSqare;
            while(true)
            {
                sum = lTemp + N;
                result = Math.Sqrt(sum);
                isSqare = result % 1 == 0;
                if(n == 4)
                {
                  return -1;
                }

                if(isSqare == true)
                {
                    return Convert.ToInt32(result);
                }
                N++;
            }
            return -1;
      }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please don't spam language tags. Only use the one for the language you are using. I assume that is C# - the other languages are irrelevant.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask].

Comment: `isSqare = result % 1 == 0;` is probably not what you want. modulo 1 is always 0.

Comment: If `N` must be square, you could use the relation `sum = n + N*N`. Besides, if `sum = x*x`, you could try to use the relation `(x+N)(x-N) = n`. But I did not go further ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `N` (square) is `p^2`, and `n+N=r^2`, you can write

```
n + p^2 = r^2
n = r^2 - p^2
n = (r - p) * (r + p)
```

If we represent `n` as product of pair of divisors:

```
n = a * b     // let a<=b
a * b = (r - p) * (r + p)
```

We have system

```
r - p = a
r + p = b
```

and

```
p = (b - a) / 2
```

When `p` is the smallest? In the case of maximal close factors `b` and `a`. So we can try to calculate divisors starting from square root of `n`. Also note that `a` and `b` should have the same parity (to make `p` integer)

Pseudocode:

```
int N = -1;
for (int a = Math.Ceiling(Math.Sqrt(n)) - 1; a > 0; a--) {
   if (n % a == 0) {
      int bma = n / a - a;
      if (bma % 2 == 0) {
         int p = bma / 2;
         int N = p * p;
         break;
      }
   }
}
```

Examples:

```
n = 16
first divisor below sqrt(16) a = 2, b=8
p = 3, 16 + 9 = 25

n = 13
first divisor below sqrt(13) a = 1, b=13
p = 6, 13 + 36 = 49

n = 72
first divisor below sqrt(72) is a = 8, b= 9 - but distinct parity!
so the next suitable pair is a = 6, b = 12
p = 3, 72 + 9 = 81
```

Comment: Note that every odd number can be written as the difference of successive squares, and every number divisible by 4 can be written as the difference of squares 2 apart. Further, (a+b) has the same parity as (a-b) so if one is divisible by 2 then both are. That means that the only inputs with no solution are k s.t. k mod 4 = 2.

Comment: You can do this more efficiently. In O(1), confirm a solution exists and find the worst solution (squares with roots separated by 1 or 2). Then do binary search on squares separated by 2k + (original separation), noting that on each iteration the larger square must decrease. If r is the larger square of the worst solution, this is O(log r + log log r + log log log r + ...). I think it might be O(log r) but haven't done the analysis.